# Android Google maps in Fragment showing only once

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im using google maps v2 fragment in a navigation drawer fragment.

i can choose it from the navigation everything is fine.

When i switch to an other fragment and back the map isn't shown

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;


          googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}}
```

My fragment_layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="de.sw2016.bebudget.fragment.HomeFragment">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Are you recreating the instance of that fragment when you are coming back to it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i check what item is selected and reload the fragment.

```
private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
            return mapFragment;
        case 1:
            // photos
            PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
            return photosFragment;
        case 2:
            // movies fragment
            MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
            return moviesFragment;
        case 3:
            // notifications fragment
            NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            return notificationsFragment;

        case 4:
            // settings fragment
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        default:
            return new MapFragment();
    }
}


 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.nav_map:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MAP;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_photos:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_movies:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_notifications:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about_us:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }
```